# Prove the nerve of a category is equivalent to the nerve of its opposite

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory

I know the result should be true, but I saw this very interesting proof [here](https://math.mit.edu/%7Embehrens/TAGS/Isaacson_exer.pdf):

The idea is to find a category (the twisted arrow category), having adjunctions to $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}^{\mathrm opp}$, then by some abstract homotopy theory we have the equivalence.

My question is, how could we find the adjunctions? (Namely, how to solve Exercise 1.5?)

Comment: It seems to me that you have to assume the category $\mathscr C$ has an initial and a terminal object; then, $t$ has a right adjoint, defined sending an object to its initial arrow, and dually the adjoint to $s$ is defined sending an object to its terminal arrow.

Comment: @fosco this is sufficient but not strictly necessary right? It seems to me that the twisted arrow category of the discrete category $\{0,1\}$ is again said discrete category. Both source and target maps are the identity, hence adjoint equivalences. But it has neither an initial nor a terminal object...

Comment: There is something in the claim itself that fails my intuition.

Comment: The nerve of the twisted arrow category $\operatorname{tw}(\mathcal{C})$ is the edgewise subdivision of the nerve of $\mathcal{C}$, and the geometric realization of the subdivision of a simplicial set is homeomorphic to the geometric realization of the simplicial set.  In other words, it's true that $N\mathcal{C} \simeq N\operatorname{tw}(\mathcal{C})$, but I also don't see a way to prove this with adjunctions.